# Libgdx Scene2d Image from NinePatchDrawable doesn't rotate

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

I am creating an image using NinePatchDrawable and trying to rotate it using rotateBy method simply, but it is not rotating somehow. I am using following code snippet:

```
TextureAtlas ninePatchAtlas = game.getAssetsInterface().getTextureAtlas(Constants.GAME_ATLAS);
AtlasRegion region = ninePatchAtlas.findRegion("drawPatch");
NinePatch ninePatch = new NinePatch(region, 59, 59, 59, 59);
NinePatchDrawable ninePatchDrawable = new NinePatchDrawable(ninePatch);
Image image = new Image(ninePatchDrawable);
image.setOrigin(image.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2);
image.setPosition(200, 400);
image.setWidth(150);
image.rotateBy(45);
```

rotate is working if I use another drawable instead of NinePatchDrawable on constructor of Image. Is there anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: NinePatch doesn't support rotation. You would have to subclass it and override its draw method to get it working. Image only supports rotation on Drawables that implement TransformDrawable (of which TextureRegionDrawable is the only one unless you create your own).

Comment: In those cases it might also help to wrap it in a Table, use setTransform(true) on it, and rotate the table instead.

Answer (score 2):

After investigating I have decided to use Containers as follows:

```
TextureAtlas ninePatchAtlas = game.getAssetsInterface().getTextureAtlas(Constants.GAME_ATLAS);
AtlasRegion region = ninePatchAtlas.findRegion("drawPatch");
NinePatch ninePatch = new NinePatch(region, 59, 59, 59, 59);
NinePatchDrawable ninePatchDrawable = new NinePatchDrawable(ninePatch);
Image image = new Image(ninePatchDrawable);
image.setWidth(150);

Container<Image> container = new Container<Image>(image);
container.fill();
container.setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
container.setOrigin(container.getWidth() / 2, container.getHeight() / 2);
container.setTransform(true);
container.setPosition(image.getX(), image.getY());
container.rotateBy(45);
```

You can add container directly to stage or use its draw method in your custom widget implementation.